Just one line for each key
I'm using IMB DB2
Table People with composite primary key
| key_a    | key_b     | Name... | age... | e-mail...
| -------- | --------|
| 120      | 2245    |
| 140      | 5689    |

Table Order with composite primary key and People key
| key_people_a    | key_people_b    | key_order_a      | key_order_b | description... | 
| --------        | --------        |                  |             |
| 120             | 2245            | 123              | 789
| 120             | 2245            | 123              | 456
| 140             | 5689            | 123              | 321

I would like to have a Select on Order Table who shows only one line for each people
Example:
| key_people_a    | key_people_b    | key_order_a      | key_order_b | description... | 
| --------        | --------        |                  |             |
| 120             | 2245            | 123              | 789
| 140             | 5689            | 123              | 321


Why did you pick 789 instead of 456 for the first row? Any, randomly, the highest, the lowest... etc.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

With a CTE and ROW_NUMBER ypoi can achieve your wanted result.
But that looks like a very bad design, so you should look up normalization  and reconsider your approach
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
    p.key_people_a    , p.key_people_b    , p.key_order_a      , p.key_order_b , p.description
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PSRTITON BY p.key_people_a, p.key_people_b  
ORDER BY key_order_b  DESC as rn
FROM Order  o JOIN People p ON p.key_A = p.key_people_a    AND p.key_b      = p.key_people_b    )
SELECT     key_people_a    , key_people_b    , key_order_a      , key_order_b , description
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1 

